# Rigify - Envelopes look huge

Tags: rigging, armature, rigify

i am having issues rigging my mesh to the armature and i was wondering if is it normal for the envelopes to look like this

Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Envelope distance can be set in the properties panel, selecting bone options in pose mode. If you select more than one bone, you can enter a new distance value and  keep pressed Alt key before using Enter to validate the new value, so to assign the new value to all selected bones.

Anyway using bone envelope is just one of the binding methods, the most common is using vertex weights, with automatic weights and/or weight painting and/or direct weight assignements.

[image]

Comment: Automatic weight parenting looks like if it was following the envelope weights, IE moving the forearm makes the neck, ear and part of the head move with it, like it's affecting an area so BIG for some reason. What oculd be the issue?

Comment: It depends by geometry and topology, but weights have the advantage to be tweakable. Every automatic function needs some tweaks for best results. If topology is well distribuited and bones well placed, automatic weights generally does a good job.